# any way to combine grep and tail to monitor table creation from command line

Tags: grep, tail

I have a process which is dumping data to a file.  It is a list of transactions and typically is about 3.8G in size.

to do a `tail -f file.txt` is not very useful, however, each batch of transactions begins with:

```
START TRANSACTION: xyz
```

and there are only a couple hundred of those.

Is there any way to combine `tail -f` and `grep "START TRANSACTION:"` in such a way to get the following output:

```
START TRANSACTION: abc
START TRANSACTION: def
START TRANSACTION: ghi
...
```

dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically" and can you not just pipe the `tail -f` into `grep`?

Comment: This has been answered very nicely here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866416/tail-f-show-last-x-lines-that-match-a-pattern

Comment: Pipe it? `tail -f file | grep ...` and look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream if you get buffering issues

Answer (score 3):

Reading the SO question you linked, it seems like:

```
tail -f -n +1 file.txt | grep "START TRANSACTION"
```

should do what you want. The `-n` option tells tail how many lines to output (if given a plain number); if instead given a number starting with `+`, it starts from that line. So that'll start from the first line.